# IOS AR Build using ARkit, ARfoundation and LWRP Render Meshes Partially

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, lwrp

When I make my IOS build using ARFoundation, ARKit and LWRP then its render meshes partially in AR view. I am using Unity 2018.3.11f1 and LWRP 4.8.0. Any Help? Why meshes render partially?

[See what I tried](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12r-VY39KbO3HJjYjqq3rZB1VJPpBihAN/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the minimum and maximum render distance on your camera. Cameras always render objects that are within their max and min distance, missing anything else. Your video looks as though your meshes are either too large or too small, so they don't fit in your camera's render distance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try that

Comment: Hi, I have tried to change Camera max and min distance, but i could not resolved the issue :(